# jQuery datePicker only shows on first instantiation of page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have several pages that are called from a main menu and load via jQuery into a content div.  Most of these pages include a jQuery UI datePicker widget.

In every case, the datePicker works fine when the page is the first "datepicker page" loaded from the menu (index.php).

However, once the initial "datepicker page" is replaced, (even if it is replaced with itself), datePicker fails to function.

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    showOn: "focus",
    showOtherMonths:true,
    selectOtherMonths:true,
    numberOfMonths:[4,3],
    defaultDate : -330
   });

$(function() {
     $("input#begdate" ).datepicker();
     $("input#enddate" ).datepicker();
     $("input#received").datepicker();
     $("input#due").datepicker();
     $("input#dtpaid").datepicker();
 });
```

If I load a page other that a datePicker page, then the first page loaded with a datepicker functions normally.

Thanks!

Okay, I have changed things a bit.  But I still have the same result.  This code is the first code in the script (after document.ready) for the associated page

```
$(function() {
       init_datepickers();
     });


      function init_datepickers() {
         $( "input#received" ).datepicker();
         $( "input#due" ).datepicker();
         $( "input#eddue" ).datepicker();
         $( "input#edreceived" ).datepicker();
     }
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work.  It works perfectly as long as the page is stand alone and not loaded into a div.

Sorry to be so thick!

Answer (score 1):

You can either reinitialize all datapicker elements with something like:

```
$('.datepickerDIV').load('name_of_file.php', function(){
    $( ".datepickerDIV" ).datepicker();
});
```

Or, you can include script tags with same information inside loading content. First is obviously preferable, but the second method also works.

**another_page.php**

```
<script>
    $( "#datepicker3" ).datepicker();
</script>
<div id="datepicker3" class="datepickerDIV"></div>
```

Comment: Good one for the reinitialize. He should do it in a callback after the new content loads.

Comment: Thanks, Barry, I improved the clarity. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only initialise them on first load `$()` - each new datepicker needs to also be initialised after it has been loaded.

You can give all your datepickers a css class, eg `css='data-datepicker'` and then initialise them everytime you load new content:

```
$(function() {
    init_datepickers();
});

function init_datepickers() {
    $(".data-datepicker").datepicker();
}

...
    $.ajax(...
    ).complete(function() { init_datepickers(); })
```